# How to write an encoding specificed csv file in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to write a GBK encoding csv file from a DataFrame. I find the option `"encoding"` in `CSVOptions` and it works well when I read a GBK encoding file with `option("encoding", "GBK")` in local environment.  But when I use the `write` function like below

```
df.repartition(1).write.option("header", value = true).option("encoding", "GBK").csv("F:\\project\\test1")
```

The csv file I got is always in UTF8 encoding. I have tried to change the encoding option value to ISO-8859-1 or another encoding format, it doesn't change the output csv file encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Even I'm having the issue.
I have a csv file which is generated using .net C#, where encoding is mentioned as ISO-8559-1.
When I open the file in winmerge, default encoding is showing as Windows-1252.
But the csv file which is generated using

```
pdata.coalesce(1).write().format("csv")
.option("header","true").option("delimiter",";").option("encoding","ISO-8859-1")
.save("target/temp/csv/");
```

generates a csv file and when I open the file in winmerge it shows UTF-8 encoding